# Insert Date and Time columns in SSRB

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am attempting to generate a report that will have data automatically inserted into it from a server. Normally, I insert a variable from fields in the data set and run the report. However, the task I have been given is to insert date/time columns with every value column and report builder doesn't seem to like that. It inserts a single date/time column on the far left and then all the values. If I try to put a date/time column in between values, it pushes that column to the far right/last column.

[image: Example]

It should go

```
datetime,value1, 
datetime,value2...
```

and so on.
At present it goes like

```
datetime,value1,value2...datetime.
```

Is this achievable?
And if so, how can I do this?

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to SO. You'll need to provide more info. In particular show a sample of the data that comes from your dataset and what you expect the output to look like. I suspect what you want to do is perfectly possibly, it's just not clear what you want from your question.

Comment: Hi Alan,
Thank you for the welcome, I have uploaded a snip it of what I am trying to achieve. In the blue is the format I am trying for, in yellow is what SSRB is generating. 
Thank you

Comment: Still need more info. What does the data look like that comes from your dataset and how is the data supposed to be ordered? Is this a 3 column layout of a single list (so cells C2 & D2 come after A33 and B33)? or is there some logic to determine what dates/values go in each column? Try to format the sample data and expected output as though you were saying "if I have this data, I expect the result to be this" and makes sure there there is variant in the data so we can understand who it is supposed to work. At the moment it's difficult as all your data data is identical.

Comment: Please add a tag for the version of ReportBuilder that you are using

Comment: HI Alex.. purely looking at the blue columns.. and the way it is structured.. looks like you need a matrix to get the job done.. however, without actually knowing what you have as a dataset it's hard to tell.. everything you have in blue is the same data

Comment: Hi All, 
Ok, I have values coming in from a server, they are float values and they are needing to be logged every x hours. The data order is predefined, with some columns being composed of the sum of elements of 2 other columns (A1+B1=C1) ect. I uploaded a more accurate representation of what I trying to achieve. Thank you all for the assistance.